# jQuery Detect Dynamic Form value Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form that needs to detect the field sequence.

Here my js file

```
var i = 1;

$("a.add-line").click(function(){
    $("div.items").append(
        $('<div>').attr('id','image-preview-'+i).attr('style','background-image: url(http://xxxxxxx);')
    );
    i++;
});

$("#image-preview-"+i).change(function() {
    ....
    // "#image-preview-"+i updated.
    ....
});
```

I need to detect `image-preview-'+i` which sequence was changed and re append it.

my code was working as well, but only change the first image, and if I change other fields, its append to the first field.

I know `$("#image-preview-"+i)` was wrong since `i++;` is inside `$("a.add-line")`.

I don't have an idea of how to make its work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the event after you appended the html into the div.

Try this

```
$("a.add-line").click(function(){
    $("div.items").append(
        $('<div>').attr('id','image-preview-'+i).attr('style','background-image: url(http://xxxxxxx);')
    );
    i++;

    $('div.items').on("change", "#image-preview-"+i, function (e) {
      .....
     });
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: still not work, when `i` value is &gt than 1, like 2 or other, whenever I change the image, it's going to `i` value. not the actual image sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this...

```
    var i = 1;

    $("a.add-line").click(function(){
        $("div.items").append(
            $('<div>').attr('id','image-preview-'+i).attr('style','background-image: url(http://xxxxxxx);')
       );

        $("#image-preview-"+i).change(function() {
        ....
        });
        i++;
    });
```

Comment: already do that, still not work. when `image-preview-1` changed, but already 3 images, `image-preview-3` changed anywhere I do change, since `i` is 3.

Comment: Can you please share your code which you've written in $("#image-preview-"+i).change(function() {
        ....
        });?????

Comment: it's working now. I just capture the form `id`. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, the trick is capture the id.

so the code would be:

```
var i = 1;

$("a.add-line").click(function(){
    $("div.items").append(
        $('<div>').attr('id','image-preview-'+i).attr('style','background-image: url(http://xxxxxxx);')
    );
    i++;
});

$("#image-preview-"+i).change(function() {
    ....
    $(this.id) <- updated.
    ....
});
```